# Typescript generates typescript instead of javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2017, screeps

So I wanted to start rewriting my code from Screeps using Typescript. But for some reason instead of generating a Javascript code, it generates the same typescript code. Am I missing something from tsconfig.json file?

Left Typescript, right suppose to be Javascript

[image]

tsconfig.json File

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "lib": [ "esnext" ],
    "target": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "../",
    "baseUrl": "src/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Maybe I am missing from this file, I am new to typescript.
Using Visual Studio 2017 Community.

Comment: The right pane looks like correct Javascript to me...? What part of it is invalid as Javascript?

Comment: Where you expecting ES5 output instead of ES6/ES2015?

Comment: Because I expected the class to be converted to a function, similar to this video: https://youtu.be/yn1IScE-TQQ?t=4m17s

Comment: Yes, that's correct after I changed to ES5 that generated the output that I expected, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output *is* JavaScript, compliant with ES6 (also known as ES2015). `export`, `const`, `class`, etc are all legal JavaScript.

If you want to generate code to run on old browsers, change `target` to `es5` or `es3`

Comment: Great, setting target to es5 solved the problem for me, thank you.